# Symfony2 form type customization

Tags: forms, symfony, entity

I need help with this since I just can't figure it out by myself even after reading and examining all resources I found on the internet.

I have an Image entity. It has 3 mapped properties.

1. id
2. location
3. thumb_location

And I have custom ImageSelectType form type which extends AbstractType:

`buildForm` function looks like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $em = $options['em'];

    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $result = $qb->select('i')
            ->from('BloggerBlogBundle:Image', 'i')
            ->leftJoin('i.articles', 'a')
            ->where('a is NULL')
            ;

    $builder
        ->add('images', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'BloggerBlogBundle:Image',
                'query_builder' => $result,
                                    'required' => true,
                                    'multiple' => false,
                                    'expanded' => true,
            )
        )
                        ->setAttribute('widget', 'imageSelect')
        ;
}
```

So it takes all images that aren't used by any article and populates form with them. With these options, I get radiobuttons, like this:

```
<div id="image_images">
    <input type="radio" id="image_images_67" name="image[images]" required="required" value="67"><label for="image_images_67" class="required">c5252b4ffc9c50540218e25be1353b33aaa4ee05.png</label>
    <input type="radio" id="image_images_68" name="image[images]" required="required" value="68"><label for="image_images_68" class="required">fcfc7d7d05d63b1f55dff8cbff0bedeb3c917dfc.jpeg</label>
</div>
```

What I want now is all radiobuttons to have custom html5 data attribute `data-thumb="thumbnail/location.png"` which would be the `thumb_location` property value of image object represented by that radiobutton.

I hope I was clear enough. If any more info is needed I will provide it. 
I've read so much about this but I think I'm imagining things more complex then they actually are. At one point I just wanted to say 'Oh, forget it, I'll just render this manually' and use:

```
{% for choice in form.vars.choices %}
    <input type="radio" data-thumb="{{choice.thumb_location}}" />
{% endfor %}
```

But I really want to use good practices that this amazing framework provides....Sometimes just don't seem as obvious to me as they should.

Comment: The Symfony2 cookbook has an extensive article on [how to create a custom form field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html).

Comment: As I said, I've read it and I still don't get it. I really don't find it extensive at all, or I'm just too stupid to get obvious things.....I even started examining Symfony's source code and I see that they use PHP templates internally in Forms component while I use Twig.

Comment: I don't find any signs of an attempt to build a custom form field type as documented in that article in your code samples. Why don't you try again and ask about the specific problems you encounter while doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I thought this was relating to this object as the FormType is. So in this case I see the possibility to set a variable withe the buildView method.

```
 /**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
     $view->vars['thumb'] = $options['thumb'];
}
```

You can set this option whether in the ->add(x, x, array('thumb_location' => 'location'))
(or in the setDefaultOptions method).

But now I am not sure to be honest. Because you would need to set in the view like this:

```
<input data-thumb="{{ thumb }}" type="radio" id="blog_article_image_17" name="blog_article[image]" required="required" value="17">
```

And this means you make `<input data...` by hand again.

Not sure if this is possible in your case but I think it would be nice to define a second FormType for the radio input field:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
   ...this is your current form builder....

   ->add('radio', MyRadioType());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question, you want to set the `data-thumb` directly within the form builder, right?

So the form builder contains mains features (http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.html) including the `setAttribute(string $name, string $value)` method.

You could do something like:

```
setAttribute('data-thumb', $yourvalue);
```

To apply these attributes in your input field, you need to set attributes in your twig template:

```
 <input type="radio" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} />
```

Comment: Yes,its exactly that but I don't need it in that fieldtype, i need it in CHILD filed type. ImageSelectType is a 'entity' type form which creates radiobuttons. I need to set radiobuttons inside of it to have thumbnail locations stored as attribute. I tried this: http://pastebin.com/RRfBtqE7 as you suggested but nothing changes.

Comment: To clarify, here is what I get in HTML and what I want to get. 

http://pastebin.com/LGSespKv